# java.net.URISyntaxException. sbt - space in path

Tags: scala, sbt

I have tried this behavior on `sbt 0.13.16` and `1.0.1`. Not just for `sbtVersion` but with even the other sbt commands. I believe the problem is because of the empty space in the path (`/C:/Users/Jatin Puri/.sbt/preloaded/`)

```
D:\spark-stemming>sbt sbtVersion
"C:\Users\Jatin Puri\.sbt\preloaded\org.scala-sbt\sbt\"1.0.1"\jars\sbt.jar"
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 21: file:/C:/Users/Jatin Puri/.sbt/preloaded/
    at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URI.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URL.toURI(Unknown Source)
    at sbt.Resolver$url$.apply(Resolver.scala:269)
    at sbt.Classpaths$.sbt$Classpaths$$bootRepository(Defaults.scala:1658)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$appRepositories$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1634)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$appRepositories$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1634)
```

What can be a fix for it? (I can't of-course change the user name). Is this an sbt bug? (I can't believe if it is so, because it is so normal and probable).

Could a fix be to change the default path away from `~/.sbt`? But I have not been able to do that. How do we change this default path.

Comment: You can try to load sbt with different global directory with `-sbt-dir ...` option. Another one is `-no-global`, which will make it use global cache, but not `~/.sbt`. Anyway, I think it's not a solution.

Answer (score 1):

This problem has been reported on the sbt issue tracker: [sbt/sbt#1412](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/1412) and [sbt/sbt#3253](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/3253). You can help debugging it by writing there and providing more information about your project setting and sbt installation.